# set control ID using string.concat

Tags: asp.net

i've some code in c#, in which there are many lines of code where the ID of a control is set by string.concat. For ex:

```
private genericControl ctrlGrid;
genericControl = Page.LoadControl(obj);
genericControl.ID = string.concat("gridControl");
```

Can there be any specific reasons for setting the ID using string.concat? 
Can there be any performance hit associated with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use just:

```
genericControl.ID = "gridControl";
```

EDIT:
Take a look at `string.Concat()` method that will be used when you are passing one parameter:

```
public static string Concat(params string[] values)
{
    if (values == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    }
    int totalLength = 0;
    string[] strArray = new string[values.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = values[i];
        strArray[i] = (str == null) ? Empty : str;
        totalLength += strArray[i].Length;
        if (totalLength < 0)
        {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();
        }
    }
    return ConcatArray(strArray, totalLength);
}
```

So yes, it has performance overhead and better to use just string.

Comment: yeh, i get that. but is there any performance overhead if they are set by string.concat?